# Фиксация элемента form в середине страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы элемент form всегда был посередине страницы, не используя margin?

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, использовать лёгкую библиотеку к jQuery - jquery.centerIt.js:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.centerIt.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('form').centerIt({ 
            parent: '#sample1-parent'//родительский элемент
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

[ссылка на демо и файлы](https://github.com/jkneb/centerIt)

Comment: Я нашел спомоб на CSS body {text-align: center; margin: 0px; }

Answer (score 2):

Методов много, зависит от условий (известны ли высота и/или ширина и т.д.). Вот подборка: [Centering Block Element](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Centering_Block_Element).

Answer (score 0):

через position